# How can I change an elements color when clicked a second time?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a like button for a website I'm making and I have a simple piece of JavaScript that changes the color to red when it is clicked, but how can I make the color alternate so if you click it again it goes back to black than changes to red again if you click it another time etc.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("like");

btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick() {
    btn.style.color = 'crimson';
});
```

Comment: `btn.style.color = btn.style.color == 'crimson' ? 'black' : 'crimson';`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Would you mind posting this as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Setting inline styles is really the last resort when styling is needed. Instead, CSS classes should be used.

Comment: So I really should do what @ScottMarcus said?

Comment: Yes. Working with any inline code is discouraged as it makes the HTML more complicated, leads to duplication of code, makes it hard to override, and doesn't scale well.

Comment: Okay thank you for informing me so I know for next time. Also sorry I @ you I didn't realize at first you were the person I mentioned haha.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Johnny's suggestion may not work, since colours are often returned in `rgb()` format, regardless of the way in which they were set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) method of the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

And, as a general rule, you should strive to avoid setting an "inline style" (`element.style.xxx = xxx`) as this creates a style for the element that can only be overridden by another inline style, leads to duplication of code, and therefore code that doesn't scale well. Instead, always try to work with  CSS classes.

```js
document.getElementById("like").addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.active { color:crimson; }
```

```html
<button id="like">Like</button>
```

Comment: Of course. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this steps

First let's take a counter variable

```
let clickCount = 0;
```

Then add click event.Hare is your code:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("like");
    
            let clickCount = 0;
            btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
                clickCount++;
    
                if (clickCount > 1) {
                    btn.style.color = "red";
                }
            });
```

```html
<button id="like">Like</button>
```

Comment: With this code, you have to press the button twice to get it to change color (because your `if` condition uses `>`, rather than `>=`. Also, once the color turns to red, it stays that way for all subsequent clicks, which is not what the OP is asking for. Really, there is no reason to write out this logic in the first place when `.classList.toggle()` exists.